# How to find path between two nodes iteratively in bst?

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Let's say, this is node class.

```
class Node{
      string name;
      int key; // the value to determine where to go left or right
      Node* lChild;
      Node* rChild;
}
```

I know how to find recursively. But, Do you have any advice on how to iteratively find the path between two nodes?

```
vector<string> find_path(string a, string b){
    vector<string> tmp;
    Node* head_node = head;
   
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: recursion can be turned into iteration, if you show your code maybe we can help with that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818,HI, Which part do you want me to show you? It's more like idea of how to find path between two nodes.

Comment: "any advice" is too vague. What did you try? Where did you get stuck? If a recursive method is all you can come up with then write that first.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, I am sure you can read most of the recursive stuff online. ok my problem I am stuck at is that I am not sure how to print the path from a node to b node iteratively because it's iterative process.

Comment: Your `find_path` has lots of references to undeclared variables/properties. Also, what relevance does it have that you have a BST, when you are not searching by key, but by string? The key information seems irrelevant to this question, and so it is also irrelevant that you have a BST.

Comment: @trincot, it's a pre-traversal method that I am using.

Comment: You removed the code, so there is no traversal at all. Please show the code you wrote and where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To find a path between the nodes holding keys x and y in a BST, you can use the following procedure:

1. Walk down the tree, searching for x and y, until either (1) you encounter x, (2) you encounter y, or (3) you encounter a node where x is on one side and y is on the other.
2. If you found x or y in the previous step, simply walk down the tree searching for the other, writing down the sequence of nodes you encounter as you do, and return that sequence.
3. Otherwise, suppose you stop at a node z where x and y are on opposite sides. Walk from z to x and z to y, writing down the paths as you do. Then, glue the path from x to z and the path from z to y together to get the path you want.

This approach can be done iteratively - you just need the ability to iteratively descend a tree while writing down the paths you take.